# Can I chgrp a directory through Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, permissions, subclipse

I develop on one machine in Eclipse. When I commit the files to the server, the owner is set to 'svn' and the group is set to 'daemon' (neither of which are me).  I'm trying out a framework. It requires one of its directories to be writable by Apache. Apache is group 'nobody'.  I'd like to `chgrp nobody /path/to/directory` but I can't do it directly since svn owns the files.

Is there a way in Eclipse (Subclipse module) that I can send a chgrp command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im confused by your question.. When you commit files they should be going to the repository. As long as the files within the repository are writable bay all the svn user accounts that part of it is fine.

Now if you are going to deploy these to a server for test/production/whtever you want to do a svn checkout or export. Typically you login is as whatever FTP user you might login with an ftp client (so that you know apache can read files by this user:group) and you then issue the export or checkout command and it performs that operation as the user that issued the command.

In short you should never have a situation where anything in your checkout/export is owned by anyone other than the user you checked out/exported with. So you should be able to ssh in (or perhaps us ftp/sftp) to change the permission/user/group of the files youve deployed. But this has nothing to do with Eclipse, or even SVN.

Comment: I believe our sysadmin set things up so that the export happens automatically. I'm not very familiar with the guts of the whole thing and I thought perhaps this might be a "standard" option, in which case there might be a "standard" way of affecting the export.

Comment: Ahhh... No there are no filesystem ownership/permission controls in SVN. There is a proper for Executable but thats it. You best bet here is to write a script that performs tasks like this. The have him run that command as part of his automation. That way you have some control over what happens post checkout.